# Fastest way to clear out a large area down to bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm thinking of building a large mobfarm (standard spawn on pressure plates, piston pushes the mob off, dies from fall damage and a waterflow collects the drops).

However, to maximize efficiency I want to build it at bedrock-level (due to lc values), meaning I need to clear out the area that I plan to build this on. Since mobs spawn within 128 blocks, this means I'll need to clear out a 128-radius circle from the collection point, which is a good few million blocks.

I realize the simplist option is to build it in the sky, but due to minecraft's lc value mechanics, the spawn rate will go down significantly and I want it to be as efficient as possible. I've tested with JL2579's mob farm design at bedrock compared to y=180, and the bedrock farm spawned about 2-3x faster.

I don't have any TNT right now (obtaining TNT being the purpose of making a mobfarm), so mining it all out by hand would probably take several weeks. Is there a good mining strategy to clear out large areas, or any better options? It's an SMP server, so no MCedit or world editing. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using mods or pure vanilla?

Comment: I created a gorge about this size and it took several weeks *in creative mode* to do (console, so no editing tools), and a large part of it was with TNT columns.  Of course, I also did it in an area with (shallow to moderate depth) water, so I had to fill that with sand first...

Answer (score 6):

The best would be to build it in stages.

- You start in one corner of the future, large spawner to make a small spawner only to craft TNT.
- Then you make a tunnel around the planned perimeter of the spawner while the spawner is producing.
- Then you use that TNT to start mining blocks on the opposite end of the spawner area and work your way back to the place you started.
- While your small spawner is producing TNT, you can work on the details of the spawner in the TNT mined areas.

In the end you will have the mob spawner of the size you need.

Comment: TNT is very inefficient for clearing out stone.

Answer (score 6):

If you are stubborn on having it at bedrock and digging out that area I suggest you collect a few diamonds, make an enchantment table and/or anvil and try to make a *Efficiency IV & Unbreaking III* pickaxe. This will be the quickest way of clearing out huge areas of stone.

However, in my opinion your best choice is to build it in the sky, check out [MonkeyFarm's mob spawners](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL19AA4777BBF7260A) (YouTube Playlist). His are really good and don't require digging for days.

What ever you do don't use TNT, TNT against stone only breaks a small area. Unless you have lots of gun powder, and I mean thousands of pieces (which you realistically need a HUGE mob spawner), you can't clear that sort of area with it.

Comment: Yes, TNT would be very inefficient for clearing out stone.

Comment: It is so much fun to use a pickaxe with high level Efficiency. The drawback is that it takes many trials and errors to get your first intended enchantment. But, once you have it, you can renew it forever using an Anvil. (You may need an XP farm, or go scavenge for that high XP yielding semi-abundant nether material whose name slips my mind.) Unbreaking will reduce the frequency that you need to do this.

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper Quartz :)

Answer (score 1):

No there's no efficient way to detroy it all without TNT. You'll have to mine every block.

If you have a lot of gold I suggest you to use it to make tools, since they are faster at mining and have more chance of getting good enchantment but has less durability.

Also, I'd suggest you to call some friends because it's going to be a pretty long ride.

Comment: Gold tools also enchant better than any other type of tool - good for making an Efficiency IV & Unbreaking III pickaxe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flatification terraformer from IndustrialCraft2 or the quarry from Buildcraft if you have access to either of those mods.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind cheating a bit, you could install TMI and enchant a pickaxe to level.127 enchantments( this is insanely fast). * Good armor stops you from hitting the ground too hard every 6 seconds, so cheat some of that too!

Answer (score -1):

Check out some of Ilmango's world eaters, they will allow you to afk while a flying machine that is duplicating tnt clears out your area for you.